# Using coefficient of variation (CV) for GCaMP6 'synchronised episode' spikes, good idea or not?

Tags: neuroscience, statistics, neuron

Using GCaMP6 we have recorded fluorescence activity of kisspeptin neurons that exhibit synchronised pulsatile firing activity. I measured the intervals between each episode, which are quite variable. However, I am unsure whether or not using the coefficient of variation to analyse their variability is a good idea (since most papers I read have applied it to individual neuronal firing to analyse variability between spike intervals but not to population spike activity). Also, do I need a minimum number of 'spikes' to use CV (since in my recordings there are only around 4-10 spikes in around 3 hours)?

Comment: You can use the CV with a small sample but of course, it may not have converged yet. But 4-10 spikes/ 3 hours does not sound right to me. You may need to reconsider the event detection algorithm you used to get these numbers and/or the quality of the recordings. Additionally, the CV metric is useful when there is considerable bursting activity and you do not expect to see much bursting with calcium imaging given the temporal dynamics of GCaMPs.